# Java - How can a method return a variable type object without knowing the resulting type at compile time?

Tags: java, generics, interface

Let's say you have an interface and two classes which implement that interface:

```
public interface IElement {
    boolean isDisplayed();
}

public class Button implements IElement  {
    @Override
    public boolean isDisplayed() {
        // checks if displayed
        return false;
    }

    public void click() {
        // clicks
    }
}

public class Textbox implements IElement  {
    @Override
    public boolean isDisplayed() {
        // checks if displayed
        return false;
    }

    public void enterText(String text) {
        // enters text
    }
}
```

And in a completely separate class we have a method which wants to return either a Button or a Textbox depending on the value of the provided parameter. Something that like this:

```
public class WhichElement {

    public <T extends IElement> T getElement(String elementName) {

        if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase("button")) {
            return new Button();
        }
        else if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase("textbox")) {
            return new Textbox();
        }
    }
}
```

However that fails because the returned object isn't type T.
I've tried just returning the interface like this:

```
public IElement getElement(String elementName)
```

But then I can't do what I really want to do, which is this:

```
WhichElement picker = new WhichElement();
picker.getElement("button").click();  <-- errors here because it's an IElement not a Button :(
```

I could just cast it to the correct object and trust the method to return the same one as I cast it to...but that seems dangerous. I'd much rather the method determine the type of object required and return that object directly. 
Is there a way to do what I'm attempting?

Comment: You can't, because the compiler can't know that passing `"button"` to `getElement` will cause a `Button` to be returned. If you can guarantee that it is a `Button`, cast it.

Comment: Using generics, the compiler inserts a cast right where you'd need a cast if you return `IElement`. If you can't guarantee the type is correct, how do you think the compiler can?

Comment: I suggest changing parameter from String to `Class<T> clazz` and then doing `clazz.newInstance()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can cast the result of `getElement()` to `T` before returning, which will produce a compiler warning.

The warning is there because the compiler is going to insert a cast at the call site, and if the runtime result isn't the correct type, a `ClassCastException` will be thrown, from a location where there is no apparent cast. Essentially, the compiler generates the same code you'd write if `getElement()` was not generic, and simply returned `IElement`.

Instead of one factory method to produce many types, create a different factory method for each type. This will give you type safety, ensure that every element the application requires is actually provided, aid refactoring, and change runtime bugs like `getElement("buttton")` to compile-time errors.

Dependency injection is another approach: give the application a button instead of locating one itself.

Comment: The cast to T would need to occur within getElement(). Even so, he would not be able to call click() the way he wants to in his example. Still though, +1 from me in that an alternative approach should be used.

Comment: @Zachary Yes, that's what I meant but it wasn't clear, was it? I will fix that up.

Answer (score 0):

Have two methods.

```
public Button getButton() {
    return new Button();
}

public Textbox getTextbox() {
    return new Textbox();
}
```

There's not much difference, semantically and codewise

```
picker.getButton()          // Strongly typed
picker.getElement("button") // Stringly typed
```

Plus the [stringly typed](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/31876/stringly-typed) version is longer.